# Cakephp data does'nt save in multiple models association

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to save data in multiple models association but the same is not saving at all. I have all set up correctly i.e. data from form is ok (debug shows all) and find also fetches the data but couldn't understand where the problem lies. My code is follows as:

**Controller:**

```
if($url == "expense_reports") { $this->set('tab_content','Invoice - Expense Reports'); $this->render('/job/invoice2'); 
        if($this->request->is('post'))
    {//debug($this->data);
 $this->Event->Invoice->Expense->save($this->data);                         }
}
```

**Models (Associations):**

**Event**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'EventType' => array(
            'className' => 'AgencyCalendar.EventType',
            'foreignKey' => 'event_type_id'
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Invoice' => array(
            'className' => 'AgencyCalendar.Invoice',
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );
```

**Invoice**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Event' => array(
            'className' => 'AgencyCalendar.Event',
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id'
        )
    );

public $hasMany = array(
        'Expense' => array(
            'className' => 'AgencyCalendar.Expense',
            'foreignKey' => 'invoice_id',
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );
```

**Expense**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Invoice' => array(
            'className' => 'AgencyCalendar.Invoice',
            'foreignKey' => 'invoice_id'
        )
    );
```

I am also not getting any sql dump in my view for this particular action to find out what is going on actually. Also how can I save multiple rows which would be generated from my expense view. My expense view is custom url so might be it would be a cause of not showing the sql dump or is this also a cause of not saving the data at all? Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is saveAll. (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array)

```
$this->Event->saveAll($this->data);
```

This will work as long as you have:
- the model relationships setup correctly
- the correct array attributes in $this->data